# How can we prove each energy in different condition become minimum when thermal equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

My question is like the title. We know in

1. condition : const volume, entropy -> internal energy(U) reach minimum when thermal equilibrium.
2. condition : const pressure, entropy -> enthalpy(H) reach minimum when thermal equilibrium.
3. condition : const volume, temperature -> free energy(F) reach minimum when thermal equilibrium.
4. condition : const pressure, temperature -> Gibbs free energy(G) reach minimum when thermal equilibrium.
5. Thermal equilibrium = Total entropy: (S.reservoir) + (S.system), becomes maximum.

In my opinion, the above statements are all correct? I hope so, but I have no idea how to prove each statement. The following is the proof in my book for Helmholtz free energy(F) in corresponding condition. However, I don't know how to extend the thought to other three energy.
I will be very very grateful, if someone can help me.

Thank you!!
[image: Helmholtz]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your conditions 3, 4 and 5 make sense, but 1 and 2 do not.

One can fix the volume of a system, and keep it in contact with a (formally infinite) source of constant temperature, let it reach thermal equilibrium, and then its free energy F is minimal.  One can keep a system at a fixed pressure, and also keep it in contact with a (formally infinite) source of constant temperature, let it reach thermal equilibrium, and then its Gibbs free energy G is minimal.

But you cannot keep the entropy of a system **fixed**. Its entropy will increase without "asking your permission", contrary to its temperature and either its volume or its pressure which you can indeed control. So your two first conditions just do not make sense.

---

Well, as you point out, in the link you provide, they describe a "thought experiment" where a system is modified so slowly that everything is reversible. This is impossible to realize in practice, but in principle it can be at least imagined. The reason why thermal equilibrium at the end of this process leads to a minimum of the energy is explained there better than I could do.

Comment: Sorry. I can't get your point why my conditions not make sense in 1,2. Like the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy), wiki has the proof for condition 1 (however I want the proof as my textbook, from the point: maximum total entropy). Maybe the condition is difficult to achieve, but it just in theory right?

And, may you explain how to prove the condition 4 for Gibbs free energy, in the way like my textbook? Thank you very much.

Comment: I went to the link you provided. OK, yes, they do  describe a "thought" experiment, impossible to realize in practice, where a system is modified so slowly that everything is reversible ans thus no entropy is created. I don't think I can explain it more clearly than it is explained in that link. Just read it carefully, everything is there.